# Jenkins won't start: WARNING: Failed to load hudson.scm.Cvs

Tags: jenkins

I recently upgraded Jenkins from 1.506 to 1.515

After the upgrade, Jenkins doesn't seem to start. The logs are full of warnings like:

```
WARNING: Failed to load hudson.scm.Cvs...
java.lang.InstantiationException: file:/jenkins/plugins/cvs/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/annotations/hudson.Extension might need to be rebuilt: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.scm.Cvs...
```

And the web GUI is inaccessible (times out).

I have downgraded to 1.506 again, but same result.
Since all the log warnings are CVS related (which I don't use, we're on svn), I tried deleting

```
/jenkins/plugins/cvs
/jenkins/plugins/cvs.jpi
```

But they come back after each restart, along with all the warnings.

I am running jenkins as a war in a dedicated tomcat running on Solaris.

Right now, Jenkins is completely inaccessible. Any pointers appreciated!

Larger snippet of logs below.

```
May 23, 2013 2:50:17 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-28080
May 23, 2013 2:50:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 538 ms
May 23, 2013 2:50:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 23, 2013 2:50:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.20
Jenkins home directory: /data/trg/tar5/jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
May 23, 2013 2:50:19 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-28080
May 23, 2013 2:50:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2182 ms
May 23, 2013 2:50:21 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
May 23, 2013 2:50:21 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
ScriptContent not available for JVM 1.5
May 23, 2013 2:50:22 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
May 23, 2013 2:50:22 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
May 23, 2013 2:50:22 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
May 23, 2013 2:50:23 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz scout
WARNING: Failed to scout hudson.scm.CvsModule$DescriptorImpl
java.lang.InstantiationException: file:/data/trg/tar5/jenkins/plugins/cvs/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/annotations/hudson.Extension might need to be rebuilt: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.scm.CvsModule$DescriptorImpl
    at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.element(IndexItem.java:144)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.scout(ExtensionFinder.java:666)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:312)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:138)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:311)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.get(ExtensionList.java:153)
    at hudson.PluginManager$PluginUpdateMonitor.getInstance(PluginManager.java:1090)
    at hudson.maven.PluginImpl.init(PluginImpl.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at hudson.init.InitializerFinder.invoke(InitializerFinder.java:120)
    at hudson.init.InitializerFinder$TaskImpl.run(InitializerFinder.java:184)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:893)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.scm.CvsModule$DescriptorImpl
    at hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader.findClass(PluginManager.java:966)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.element(IndexItem.java:134)
    ... 24 more
May 23, 2013 2:50:23 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz scout
WARNING: Failed to scout hudson.scm.CvsRepositoryItem$CvsRepositoryItemDescriptor
java.lang.InstantiationException: file:/data/trg/tar5/jenkins/plugins/cvs/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/annotations/hudson.Extension might need to be rebuilt:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.scm.CvsRepositoryItem$CvsRepositoryItemDescriptor
    at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.element(IndexItem.java:144)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.scout(ExtensionFinder.java:666)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:312)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:138)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:311)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.get(ExtensionList.java:153)
    at hudson.PluginManager$PluginUpdateMonitor.getInstance(PluginManager.java:1090)
    at hudson.maven.PluginImpl.init(PluginImpl.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at hudson.init.InitializerFinder.invoke(InitializerFinder.java:120)
    at hudson.init.InitializerFinder$TaskImpl.run(InitializerFinder.java:184)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:893)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.scm.CvsRepositoryItem$CvsRepositoryItemDescriptor
    at hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader.findClass(PluginManager.java:966)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.element(IndexItem.java:134)
    ... 24 more
May 23, 2013 2:50:23 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz scout
WARNING: Failed to scout hudson.scm.browsers.ViewCVS$DescriptorImpl
java.lang.InstantiationException: file:/data/trg/tar5/jenkins/plugins/cvs/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/annotations/hudson.Extension might need to be rebuilt:             java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.scm.browsers.ViewCVS$DescriptorImpl
    at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.element(IndexItem.java:144)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.scout(ExtensionFinder.java:666)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:312)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:138)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:311)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.get(ExtensionList.java:153)
    at hudson.PluginManager$PluginUpdateMonitor.getInstance(PluginManager.java:1090)
    at hudson.maven.PluginImpl.init(PluginImpl.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at hudson.init.InitializerFinder.invoke(InitializerFinder.java:120)
    at hudson.init.InitializerFinder$TaskImpl.run(InitializerFinder.java:184)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:893)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.scm.browsers.ViewCVS$DescriptorImpl
    at hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader.findClass(PluginManager.java:966)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.element(IndexItem.java:134)
    ... 24 more
May 23, 2013 2:50:23 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz scout
WARNING: Failed to scout hudson.scm.cvstagging.LegacyTagAction$LegacyTagActionDescriptor
```

Comment: For me, jenkins 2.7.4 stopped running a job that used cvs. "java.lang.NullPointerException
 at hudson.scm.CVSSCM.getBranchName(CVSSCM.java:312)" Manually updating the CVS areas in workspace was fine. I restarted jenkins, removed the CVS areas and in jenkins job config set CVS to require a password then not require a password and the job started working again. org.jenkins-ci.plugins:cvs:2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by clearing the "Workspace Root Directory". That is:

- Stopping Jenkins
- Moving the workspace folder (mv JENKINS_HOME/workspace JENKINS_HOME/workspace-old)
- Creating a new workspace (mkdir JENKINS_HOME/workspace)
- Restarting Jenkins

I don't what became corrupted, or how, but this solution didn't seem to have any adverse affects.
According to the Jenkins config page (Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Click Advance button near Home directory) the Workspace Root Directory is used to "Specify where Jenkins would store job workspaces on the master node."

From what I could determine, it seems to just store the files checked out from svn for each job, which are obviously easily replaced.

Anyway, all working again now.
And the upgrade worked fine second time around.